# how can edit data use $_POST in php

Tags: php, mysql

i am doing edit data and update them but data do not update. here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $tensanpham = $_POST['tensanpham'];
        $anh = $_POST['image'];
        $gia = $_POST['gia'];
        $giamgia = $_POST['giamgia'];
        $update = mysqli_query("UPDATE sanpham SET tensanpham='$tensanpham', image='$anh', gia='$gia', giamgia='$giamgia' WHERE id='$id'");
        if($update) {
            echo "update done";
        }
        else{
            echo "Fail"; }
```

Comment: SQL Injection alert!!

Comment: not alert. when i click submit , new data is restored old data

Comment: Where's your `$id` value coming from? If that variable is wrong your query will say `WHERE id = 'somethingWrong'`.  MySQL coerces strings to numbers, so that will look like `WHERE id = 0` to the query engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your MySQLi Connection String to the `mysqli_query()` function:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database_name");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $tensanpham = $_POST['tensanpham'];
    $anh = $_POST['image'];
    $gia = $_POST['gia'];
    $giamgia = $_POST['giamgia'];
    $update = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE sanpham SET tensanpham='$tensanpham', image='$anh', gia='$gia', giamgia='$giamgia' WHERE id='$id'");
    if($update) {
        echo "update done";
    } else {
        echo "Fail"; 
    }
}
```

You really should be using MySQLi prepared statements. Your current code is at risk of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `mysqli_query` is wrong. Should be corrected as :

```
$mysqli_connection = mysqli_connect($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPWD,$DBNAME);
$update = mysqli_query($mysqli_connection, "UPDATE .....");
```